# Type mismatch in argument: passed COMPLEX(8) to REAL(8)

Tags: fortran, gfortran, type-mismatch

I'm trying to compile and run a relatively old code from a PhD thesis, you can find whole code in Appendices C and D of [this](http://drmaiaprogram.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/MaiaMagrakvelidze2013.pdf) document.
Here is necessary parts from the code:

from wfMath.f90 :

```
subroutine wfmath_gaussian(widthz,pz)
 use progvars
 implicit none
 real*8, intent(in) :: widthz ! the width of the wavepacket
 real*8, intent(in) :: pz ! momentum
 integer :: nR
 real*8 :: rvalue
 complex*16 :: cvalue
 ! complex*16 :: psi !!!ORIGINAL CODE LINE 23/02/2018. Saba
 complex*16, dimension(1) :: psi !!! psi is originally defined as a scalar. But wfmath_normalize(wf) takes a rank-1 tensor as
 !argument. So here I change the declaration of psi from a scalar to a rank-1 tensor contains only one element. 23/02/2018. Saba
 real*8 :: z2
 z2 = minz + deltaz
 do nR=1, nz
 rvalue = exp( -((z2-centerz)/widthz)**2 /2 )/ (2*pi*widthz) !!!ORIGINAL CODE LINE
 !rvalue = exp( -((z2-centerz)/1.0d0)**2 /2 )/ (2*pi*1.0d0)
 cvalue = cdexp( cmplx(0.0,1.0)*(pz*z2))
 psi(nR) = rvalue * cvalue
 z2 = z2 + deltaz ! next grid position in x-direction
 enddo
 call wfmath_normalize(psi)
end subroutine wfmath_gaussian
```

from tdse.f90 - main part :

```
subroutine init
 use progvars
 use strings;
 use wfMath;
 use wfPot;
 !use tdseMethods;
 implicit none
 integer :: nloop
 real*8 :: widthz,pz

 select case (trim(molecule))
 case("H2")
 mass = 917.66d0; nz = 2048; deltaz = 0.05d0;
 case("D2")
 mass = 1835.241507d0; nz = 1024; deltaz = 0.05d0;
 case("N2")
 mass = 12846.69099d0; nz = 512; deltaz = 0.01d0;
 case("O2")
 mass = 14681.93206d0; nz =8192 ; deltaz = 0.005d0;
 case("Ar2")
 mass = 36447.94123d0; nz = 65536; deltaz = 0.002d0;
 end select

 maxt = 33072.80d0 !800fs ! maximum time
 deltat = 1.0d0 ! delta time
 widthz = 1.0d0 ! width of the gaussian
 minz = 0.05d0 ! minimum z in a.u.
 maxz = nz * deltaz ! maximum z in a.u.
 centerz = 2.1d0 ! center of the gaussian
 nt = NINT(maxt/deltat) ! time steps
 pz = 0.d0 ! not used currently

!_____________________________FFT Section____________________________________________
 deltafft = 20.d0* deltat !1.0d0*deltat ! time step for FFT
 nfft = NINT(maxt/deltafft) ! no of steps for FFT

!_________________________absorber parameters_______________________________________
 fadewidth = 10.d0 ! the width of the absorber in a.u.
 fadestrength = 0.01d0 ! the maximum heigth of the negative imaginary potential

!_________________________E FIELD section_____________________________________________
 Ewidth = 1446.2d0 !35fs ! width of the envelope
 Eo = 0.053 !E14 ! field amplitude
 Eomega = 0.057d0 !800nm ! laser frequency
! Eomega = 0.033d0 !1400nm ! laser frequency
 Ephi = 0.d0 ! carrier envelope phase
 Eto = 1000.d0 ! ecenter of the Gaussian envelope
 EoPed = 0.0755 !2E14
 EwidthPed = 826.638 !20fs
 EomegaPed = Eomega
 EphiPed = 0.d0
 EtoPed = 1000.d0
 EoPump = 0.053 !1E14 0.00285d0
 EwidthPump = Ewidth
 EomegaPump = 0.057d0
 EphiPump = 0.0d0
 EtoPump = 0.d0
 includeAbsorber = .true. ! switch for absorber
 includeField = .true. ! .false. ! switch for efield
 includePedestal = .false. ! switch for pedestal

 includeConstantPump = .true. ! .false. ! switch for efield
 useADK = .false. ! ADK switch
 calculatePowerSpectra = .true.
 calculateKERPowerSpectra = .true. !.false.

!_____________________________Printing & Plotting Filters__________________________________
 printFilter = nz
 maxFrequencyFilter = 500
 printInterval =100 !200
 ! print filter upper boundary check
 if(printFilter > nz) then
 printFilter = nz
 end if
 call allocateArrays();

 do nloop = 1,nz
 Z(nloop) = minz+ (nloop)* deltaz;

 P(nloop) = 2*pi*(nloop-(nz/2)-1)/(maxz-minz);

 E(nloop) = 27.2*(P(nloop)**2)/(4.d0*mass);
 end do

 ! call wfmath_gaussian(psiground,widthz,pz) !!! ORIGINAL CODE LINE
 call wfmath_gaussian(psiground,real(widthz),pz) ! Attempt to solve mismatch error. Does not work. Saba 24/02/2018
 ! call wfmath_gaussian(psiground,1.0d0,pz) ! Attempt to solve mismatch error. Does not work. Saba 23/02/2018
 ! call wfmath_gaussian(pz) ! Attempt to solve mismatch error. Does not work. Saba 23/02/2018

 call setabsorber_right(fadewidth, fadestrength)
 call printpsi(psiground,trim(concat(outputFolder,"psi_gausssian.dat")))

 call potentials_init(nz) !initialize potential arrays

 call read_potential();

end subroutine init
```

As far as I understand, there is no mismatch at all. widthz is declared as real*8 in main part of the code (subroutine init), and subroutine wfmath_gaussian(...) expects widthz to be a real*8. I can't see where this mismatch error occurs?

used compiler: GNU Fortran 6.3.0

used compile line: $gfortran tdse.f90

error message:

```
tdse.f90:159:118:

call wfmath_gaussian(psiground,real(widthz),pz) ! Attempt to solve mismatch error. Does not work. Saba 24/02/2018
                                                                                                                 (1)

Error: Type mismatch in argument 'widthz' at (1); passed COMPLEX(8) to REAL(8)
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please specify used compiler, used compile line and the error message.

Comment: Doesn't the definition of wfmath_gaussian have 2 arguments and the call 3?

Comment: Sorry, I was so confident that there is no mismatch, I forget to post the error message :) And yes, wfmath_gaussian takes 2 arguments. But the compiler does not throw any error or even a warning about that issue :/ That confuses me too.

Comment: psiground is not declared in the code parts you gave but probably in one of the used modules as a COMPLEX variable, hence the message. Is the routine  wfmath_gaussian defined in the module wfMath or in its own file?

Comment: Thank you @albert . psiground is a complex scalar and since it is the first argument, this error occurs. When I erase psiground, and use "call wfmath_gaussian(widthz,pz)", the code is compiled. By the way subroutine wfmath_gaussian is defined in module wfMath

Comment: The error message is clear, the actual argument psiground you say is declared as a complex variable while the corresponding dummy argument, widthz, is declared as a real. These are not the same things hence the error. Your "fix" only makes things worse by making the number of arguments wrong. The true fix is to make either psiground real, or widthz complex, but without knowing what these routines are doing I can't tell you which. Also real*8 etc. is not and has never been standard Fortran, fix this, and your "fix" doesn't trigger an error due to the lack of an interface - learn about these!